# Bitcoin Core block chain

Tags: blockchain

My C: drive is almost full from the blockchain being installed and I'm wanting to move it. I have D: drive with well over enough space and want to know if I

-Pause the install of the chain and close bitcoin
-Add the -datadir=D:\BitcoinData to the properties of BitcoinCore
-Then open BitcoinCore

I am wondering
if it will it continue from where it left off in the new directory? (With all existing blocks moved into the new directory as well)

I do NOT want to have to reinstall the chain..

Comment: Only one question per post please. Can you edit your question and split it into two, perhaps?

Comment: There I changed it to one